# CXF and spring boot actuator, actuator end points not available

Tags: spring-boot, cxf, spring-boot-actuator

I have a project setup with spring boot 1.4.2 and CXF JAXRS. I want to add spring boot actuator to the project. This is the configuration which I added to the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I create a WAR file after this and then deploy it in external tomcat server. But when I access the health URL **localhost:8080/management/health** it is giving 404 HTTP code. The server starts properly and I can see the logs with following details:

**Health configuration log**

> [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping -
>   Mapped "{[/management/health ||
>   /management/health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
>   java.lang.Object

**Servlet(s) configuration log**

> [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean
>   - Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
>
> [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping
>   filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
>
> [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping
>   filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
>
> [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping
>   servlet: 'dispatcherServletRegistration' to []
>
> [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping
>   servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
>
> [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping
>   servlet: 'CXFServlet' to [/services/*]

Comment: The answer is quite clearly in the logs... `{[/management/health || /management/health.json]` that represents a path... not `/health` but `/management/health`. It is right there...

Comment: Hey, Deinum, thank you for the comment.  I meant /management/health only. I corrected it in the question and I solved the issue as well and mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is solved and here is the details. Since CXF and spring boot together were together cofigured, both CXF REST API and actuator end point were configured for **'/'**. The name of servlet bean configured for CXF RESt end point is **dispatcherServletRegistration**. An auto configuration for CXF servlet was also happening since boot starter for CXf was there in the POM.  Hence you can find **CXFServlet** also configured for **/services/***.

> Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServletRegistration' to []
>
> Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
>
> Mapping servlet: 'CXFServlet' to [/services/*]

I removed auto configuration option (**CXFServlet**) since I have some customization required for the CXF JAXRS implementation and mapped **dispatcherServletRegistration** to **/services/*** and now everything is working fine. Now actuator works under **'/'** and CXF REST APIs under **/services**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have Spring 1.5.X , i cannot use two different base paths for CXF and Spring Actuator. I need to keep "/"  for root application path and add a RestEnpoint for returning actuator Health result.

So i use another approach when CXF returns a string result from Health Info generated on Service layer using @Autowired + ObjectMapper.

Note: you should enable the annotation context support for apply this solutions.

These following workaround works for me :

keep your CXF Servlet on "/"

In my case i'm using Camel + CXF, however all you need to do is creating the following component for build the Health object:

```
@Component
public class InfoHealthEndpoint extends HealthEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint;

    public InfoHealthEndpoint(HealthAggregator healthAggregator, Map<String, HealthIndicator> healthIndicators) {
        super(healthAggregator, healthIndicators);
    }

    @Override
    public Health invoke() {
        Health health = super.invoke();
        return new Health.Builder(health.getStatus(), health.getDetails())
                .withDetail("info", infoEndpoint.invoke())
                .build();
    }

}
```

And create a service that returns the String result for CXF response controller.

@Service
public class HealthService {

```
@Autowired
private InfoHealthEndpoint infoHealthEndpoint;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

private static final String HEALTH_UP = "UP";

public void health(Exchange exchange) throws JsonProcessingException {

    Health health = infoHealthEndpoint.invoke();
    String healthReponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(infoHealthEndpoint.invoke());

    if(!HEALTH_UP.equals(health.getStatus().getCode())){
        Response response = Response.status(503).entity(healthReponse).build();
        exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
        exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
    }else{
        exchange.getIn().setBody(healthReponse);
    }

}
```

}

NOTE: in my case, im using Apache Camel (Exchange) for set response on route, however this solution could applyable for another situation by using a simple String return.

Credits for @Danny on this answer: [Combine Spring Boot Actuator /health and /info into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275885/combine-spring-boot-actuator-health-and-info-into-one)